# GUI toggle key for wifi hotspot(on/off)

Tags: command-line, scripts, gui

I want to create a GUI widget like on/off toggle for running a set of commands.

For example, to turn wifi hotspot on and off using `ap-hotspot start/stop`.

Anybody help me...

Comment: I removed a number of my comments to make some space... One more: could you give me the output of pstree (with ap-hotspot on/off)?

Comment: great! this should do, will continue late tomorrow. You might want to remove the images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can practice a universal *method* to create a toggle script/functionality for settings, connections etc. Also, you will probably be able to reuse a great part of the code for different situations. However, an easy "all in one" solution, applicable in different situations and without *any* knowledge on, or feeling with coding is hard to give. You depend on the nature of the two states the script has to toggle between, their corresponding commands and the method you can use (or not) to check what is the current state.

Having said that, given your toggle hotspot example, below are three ready to use versions of a setup, from relatively simple to a bit more complicated. The first two are the most "universal" ones; the third is for use in Unity only.

The general "anatomy" of the toggle scripts is as follows:

```
> check what is the current_status
> if current_status = A:
      (switch icon to icon_b)
      run command to change state to B
      (check if toggle command was successful, if not > switch icon back)
> else:
      (switch launcher icon to icon_a)
      run command to change to change to A
      (check if toggle command was successful, if not > switch icon back)
```

**Toggle setup; the three examples**

1. Toggling with a single starter (desktop file) on your desktop.
2. Idem, but toggling icon as well, to show the current state
3. Toggling from an icon in the Unity launcher, with toggling icon to show the current state

Notes:

- Since you will be asked for your password, you need to install gksu if it is not on your system already. Example 3 should not be used (as it is) on 12.04 or earlier.
- Keep in mind that a script that asks for administrator's permission is a potential security risk. If you are having doubts on who is doing what on your computer, store it in a secure directory.

**1. Toggling with a single starter (desktop file) on your desktop**

The most simple one: toggling via a (fixed) starter on your desktop

*Instructions*:

Icon:

Download either one of the icons from below (right-click > safe as) safe it as `toggle_icon.png` in a location of your choice.

[image] [image]

The script:

Copy the text below, paste it in an empty file and save it as hotspot.py in a location of your choice.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

# identifying string to look for when "pstree" is run
running_id = "ap-hotspot"

def check_ifrunning(): 
    # check if hotspot is up or down
    get_pstreeinfo = subprocess.Popen(["pstree"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = (get_pstreeinfo.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8"))
    if running_id in output:
        return "running"
    else:
        return "not_running"

def toggle_connection():
    runcheck = check_ifrunning()  
    if runcheck == "not_running":
    # command to start hotspot (spaces replaced by ",")
        subprocess.Popen(["gksu", "ap-hotspot", "start"])
    else:
        # idem, stop hotspot
        subprocess.Popen(["gksu", "ap-hotspot", "stop"])

toggle_connection()
```

Create a desktop file:

Copy the text below, paste it in an empty text file. Add the correct path to the script in the `Exec=` line, the correct path in the `Icon=` line, and safe it to your desktop as `hotspot_toggle.desktop`. Make it executable and your setup should work.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Hotspot toggle
Comment=Hotspot toggle
Categories=Accessories
Exec=python3 /path/to/script/hotspot.py
Icon=/path/to/icon/toggle_icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

**2. Toggling with a single starter (desktop file) on your desktop, with icon change effect**

This is an enhanced version of the first example: the icon will change to `toggle_officon.png` / `toggle_onicon.png` on your desktop, depending on whether hotspot is on/off.

*Instructions*:

Icons:

Download *both* icons from the first example, safe them as

```
toggle_officon.png (the grey one)
toggle_onicon.png (the green one)
```

in a location of your choice.

The script:

Copy the text below, paste it in an empty file and save it as hotspot.py in a location of your choice. Add the correct paths to the lines starting with `path_todtfile =` (path to the desktop file, see further below),  `icon_offpath =` (path to toggle_officon.png) and `icon_onpath =` (path to toggle_onicon.png). Note: The "real" name of the desktop file is how you named it when you saved it. The name *you see* in your interface is defined in the `Name=` line of the desktop file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import time

wait = 10

# identifying difference on pstree command on / off
running_id = "ap-hotspot"

# pathto_desktop file
path_todtfile = "/path/to/desktop_file/toggle.desktop"
# paths to icons
icon_offpath = "/path/to/toggle_off_icon/toggle_officon.png"
icon_onpath = "/path/to/toggle_on_icon/toggle_onicon.png"

def set_icon(set_mode, state):
    if state == "running":
        iconset = [icon_onpath, icon_offpath]
    else:
        iconset = [icon_offpath, icon_onpath]
    if set_mode == "set_current":
        appropriate_iconpath = iconset[0]
    else:
        appropriate_iconpath = iconset[1]
    with open(path_todtfile, "r") as editicon:
        editicon = editicon.readlines()
    line_toedit = [editicon.index(line) for line in editicon if\
                   line.startswith("Icon=")][0]
    if not editicon[line_toedit] == "Icon="+appropriate_iconpath+"\n":
        editicon[line_toedit] = "Icon="+appropriate_iconpath+"\n"
        with open(path_todtfile, "wt") as edited_icon:
            for line in editicon:
                edited_icon.write(line)
    else:
        pass

def check_ifrunning():
    # check if hotspot is up or down
    get_pstreeinfo = subprocess.Popen(["pstree"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = (get_pstreeinfo.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8"))
    if running_id in output:
        return "running"
    else:
        return "not_running"

def toggle_connection():
    runcheck = check_ifrunning()
    set_icon("set_alter", runcheck)
    if runcheck == "not_running":
        subprocess.call(["gksu", "ap-hotspot", "start"])
    else:
        subprocess.call(["gksu", "ap-hotspot", "stop"])
    time.sleep(wait)
    runcheck = check_ifrunning()
    set_icon("set_current", runcheck)

toggle_connection()
```

Desktop file:

Create the desktop file like in example 1. Add the correct path to the script in the `Exec=` line, the path to either one of the two icons in the `Icon=` (it will be straightened out on first use), and safe it to your desktop as `toggle.desktop`. Make it executable and your setup should work.

**3. Toggling from an icon in the Unity launcher, with toggling icon to show the current state**

down / running

[image] [image]

(This example should not be used as it is on 12.04 or earlier.)

Icons:

Download *both* icons from the first example, safe them as

```
toggle_officon.png (the grey one)
toggle_onicon.png (the green one)
```

in a location of your choice.

The script:

Copy the text below. paste it in an empty file, save it as hotspot.py in a location that suits you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import getpass
import time

# time to wait, to check if hotspot was established (set correct icon)
wait = 10
# identifying difference on pstree command
running_id = "ap-hotspot"
# location of the launcher restore script
backup_copy = "/home/"+getpass.getuser()+"/.restore_currentlauncher.sh"
# name of the desktop file if hotspot is down
mention_ifdown = 'application://hotspot_off.desktop'
# name of the desktop file if hotspot is running
mention_ifup = 'application://hotspot_on.desktop'

def check_ifrunning():
    # check if hotspot is up or down
    get_pstreeinfo = subprocess.Popen(["pstree"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = (get_pstreeinfo.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8"))
    if running_id in output:
        return "running"
    else:
        return "not_running"

def read_currentlauncher():
    # read the current launcher contents
    get_launcheritems = subprocess.Popen([
        "gsettings", "get", "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher", "favorites"
        ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return eval((get_launcheritems.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")))

def set_current_launcher(current_launcher):
    # before editing the launcher, create restore script
    backup_data = read_currentlauncher()
    with open(backup_copy, "wt") as create_backup:
        create_backup.write(
            "#!/bin/sh\n\n"\
            "gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "+\
            '"'+str(backup_data)+'"'
            )
    # preparing subprocess command string
    current_launcher = str(current_launcher).replace(", ", ",")
    subprocess.Popen([
        "gsettings", "set", "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher", "favorites",
        current_launcher,
        ]) 

def set_icon(change_mode):
    # defines the appropriate icon in the launcher
    state = check_ifrunning()
    if state == "running":
        if change_mode == "set_current":
            iconset = [mention_ifup, mention_ifdown]
        else:
            iconset = [mention_ifdown, mention_ifup]
    elif state == "not_running":
        if change_mode == "set_current":
            iconset = [mention_ifdown, mention_ifup]
        else:
            iconset = [mention_ifup, mention_ifdown]
    # set the defined icon
    current_launcher = read_currentlauncher()
    if iconset[0] in current_launcher:
        pass
    else:
        index = current_launcher.index(iconset[1])
        current_launcher.pop(index)
        set_current_launcher(current_launcher)
        time.sleep(1)
        current_launcher.insert(index, iconset[0])
        set_current_launcher(current_launcher)

def toggle_connection():
    set_icon("set_alter")
    runcheck = check_ifrunning()
    if runcheck == "not_running":
        subprocess.call(["gksu", "ap-hotspot", "start"])
    else:
        subprocess.call(["gksu", "ap-hotspot", "stop"])
    time.sleep(wait)
    set_icon("set_current")

toggle_connection()
```

Two desktop files, that will switch in the launcher:

Below two desktop files you need. Open an empty text file, paste the code below (in separate files), replace the paths by the actual paths to the icon(s) you saved above, and the path to the script, and save them in `~/.local/share/applications`, as `hotspot_off.desktop`, and `hotspot_on.desktop`:

hotspot_off.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Hotspot off
Exec=python3 /path/to/script/hotspot.py
Icon=/path/to/toggle_officon/toggle_officon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

hotspot_on.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Hotspot on
Exec=python3 /path/to/script/hotspot.py
Icon=/path/to/toggle_officon/toggle_onicon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
```

Finally, drag either one of the desktop files on to the launcher. Don't worry if you picked the right one or not, it will be straightened out on first run.

Comment: @rajan Thanks for your question, it was nice working on :)